# VBA Instr search function not finding string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text file which I use multiple Instr functions to search and have no problems until I want to search the following string "Safety stop CSC ack"

The string exists in the file :

```
[170701 000741] [170701 001151] [             ] --- YTLC0 LC0/C 30: Safety stop OK
[170701 001151] [             ] [             ] --- YTLC0 LC0/C 91: PP: LM switch power failure
[170701 000734] [170701 001150] [170701 001155] --- YTIOC01 ISD1/C b15: Item CSC ack
[170701 000741] [170701 001151] [170701 001158] --- YTLC0 LC0/C 30: Safety stop CSC ack
[170701 000751] [170701 001159] [             ] --- YTPP c19: Linear motor supply Q102 OK
[170701 001151] [170701 001159] [             ] --- YTLC0 LC0/C 91: PP: LM switch OK
[170701 001151] [170701 001159] [170701 001159] --- YTLC0 LC0/C 91: PP: LM switch Auto ack
```

The weird thing is that it will find "Safety stop OK" and "Safety stop Detected"
but doesn't seem to find "Safety stop CSC ack"

I am using the following Instr command which works perfectly for all other searches I am doing

```
ElseIf InStr(1, LCase(myFaultDesc), LCase("Safety stop CSC ack"), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Make sure the variable `myFaultDesc` is set correctly, i.e. it's the text that you expect it to be.

Comment: Michal, thanks, myFaultDesc contains the whole string :    myFaultDesc : "--- YC113 IC5/I 100: Item too short Fixed" and is a type String and i just use Instr to read inside the string and then pick out what I need to work on

Comment: You don't need the `LCase` when using `InStr` with `vbTextcompare` set. It's case insensitive